# Gurobi prefix sum optimization

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, gurobi, integer-programming

Consider the following Gurobi model:

```
import gurobipy as gb
import numpy as np
N = 100
x = np.random.randint(10, high=2*N, size=N)
model = gb.Model("ACC")
amp_i_vars = model.addVars(N, vtype=gb.GRB.BINARY, name='ai')
model.setObjective(amp_i_vars.sum(*), gb.GRB.MINIMIZE)
model.addConstrs(gb.quicksum(amp_i_vars[i] for i in range(r+1)) <= x[r] 
                 for r in range(N), "SumConstr")
```

Where we are essentially just trying to fill up `ai` with as many bits as possible such that the sum of bits up to position `r` is never greater than `x[r]`.

My question is whether or not GurobiPy is "smart" in the way it goes through the constraint, i.e. if it computes a prefix sum of `ai` or instead, actually recomputes the sum for each `r<N`. The former case would be linear time, whereas the latter would be quadratic. I have a LP which contains many such sums and constraints, and I'm  wondering or not it would be better to create a separate variable to store the prefix sum of each sequence to prevent GurobiPy from recomputing the sum for every constraint, but I don't want to have to do that if it already is smart enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your exact formulation has O(N^2) non-zeros, so you are stuck with a O(N^2) algorithm to build it.  You can avoid re-creating the expression by this more procedural loop.

```
import gurobipy as grb
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(10)

N = 5000
x = np.random.randint(10, high=2*N, size=N)
obj = -np.random.randint(10, high=2*N, size=N)
model = gb.Model("ACC")

# more interesting objective
amp_i_vars = model.addVars(N, vtype=grb.GRB.BINARY, name='ai', obj=obj)
model.update()
cum = grb.LinExpr()
for i, ai in amp_i_vars.items():
    cum += ai
    model.addConstr(cum <= x[i])
model.optimize()
```

However, you can formulate an equivalent model with O(n) non-zeros by adding a parallel list of variables representing the cumulative sum, and using the recurrence 
*cum[i] = cum[i - 1] + x[i]*.  This will also lead to a model that solves much faster.

```
import gurobipy as grb
import numpy as np
N = 5000
np.random.seed(10)
x = np.random.randint(10, high=2*N, size=N)
obj = -np.random.randint(10, high=2*N, size=N)
model = gb.Model("ACC")

# more interesting objective function
amp_i_vars = model.addVars(N, vtype=grb.GRB.BINARY, name='ai', obj=obj)
# since cum_vars are variables, use simple upper bound
cum_vars = model.addVars(N, vtype=grb.GRB.CONTINUOUS, name='cum', ub=x)

prev_cum = 0
for i, (ai, cum) in enumerate(zip(amp_i_vars.values(), cum_vars.values())):
    model.addConstr(cum == prev_cum + ai, name="sum_constr." + str(i))
    prev_cum = cum
model.optimize()
```

For N=5000, this solves in 0.5 seconds versus 16 seconds for the dense model.

Answer (score 0):

On the modeling layer gurobipy will *not* "be smart" and apply the substitution you are describing, so it will generate the constraints one by one, recomputing the partial sums each time.  You can try introducing auxiliary variables for these partial sums, but my guess is that the modelling overhead of the "
dumb" method becomes only noticible if the sums are really large.